# How to make a nonstreamable mp4 streamable from a JS browser client?

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, libav

For my service we are sending videos that need processing. Unfortunately some of the videos are non streamable. By that I mean the metadata information is at the end of the file and not the beginning. With ffmpeg you can make a video streamable with this command: `ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -a:v copy -a:c copy -movflags faststart output.mp4`

Is there anyway I can replicate ffmpegs `faststart` logic from a JS client?

I see that there are libaries like `ffmpeg.js` but I was hoping to avoid having a huge library in the code.

Comment: ??? https://medium.com/stackfame/how-to-run-shell-script-file-or-command-using-nodejs-b9f2455cb6b7

Comment: I'll update my question title, I mean browser client

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Yes, you can do this in javascript, But it will not achieve what you want.

When ffmpeg applies faststart, It must rewrite the entire file from beginning to end. So while yes, you could in theory do this in the browser, you would still need to download the entire file first, at which point you could just play it and not need to apply faststart.